# asp.net MVC update TextBoxFor Value from an Textbox OnChange event

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm looking for help about this subject.

I've got in my view 2 textbox.
I would like to get a value (generated in my controller) applied to textbox2 when there is an change on the textbox1.
For example I enter an username in textbox1 and textbox2 is the email address getting from controller (we can imagine that the controller check in a database or an active directory).

My code below seems not working:

In my View file I added an script section :

```
@section scripts{         
           <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">                
            function ShowPersonalPanel(myChkboxPersonalLine) {
                if (myChkboxPersonalLine.checked == false) {
                    $("#1-w").hide("fast");
                }
                else {
                    $("#1-w").show("fast");
                }
            }           
        </script>

        <script language="javascript">    
            $("#1-w").hide("fast");



            $('#myOtherGID').change(function () {
                var myOtherGID = this.value;
                $.getJSON("/PhoneController/GetEmailByGID",
                    {
                        strGID: myOtherGID
                    },
                    function (data) {
                        $('myOtherEmail').val(data);                            
                    });
            });
        </script>
    }
```

And the code in the view with textbox:

```
 <label for="myOtherGIDlbl">GID:</label>
        <label class="text" id="myOtherGIDlbl">
           @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.myOtherGID)
        </label>

        <label for="myOtherEmaillbl">Email:</label>
        <label class="text" id="myOtherEmaillbl">                
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.myOtherEmail)
        </label>
```

On my controller (named PhoneController) I added an action:

```
 public JsonResult GetEmailByGID(string strGID)
    {
        string strEmailAddress = "this is my email";

        return Json(strEmailAddress, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

As I work with an _layout.cshtml and an viewFile.cshtml, I added in the layout (in the head section) the line below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
```

What did I miss?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I've found my issue.
I've changed my javascript to make an $.ajax command:

```
script type="text/javascript">
    $('#myOtherGID').change(function () {
        var selection = $('#myOtherGID').val();
        if (selection.length > 0) {
            var url = "/Phone/GetEmailByGID";
            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetEmailByGID", "Phone")',
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data, status) {
                    alert(data);
                    },
                    error: function() {
                    alert('error');
                }
            });               
        }
    });
</script>
```

In the controller :

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetEmailByGID(string strGID)
    {
        string strEmailAddress = strEmailByGID(strGID);

        return Json(strEmailAddress);            
    }
```

After testing, I can retrive data from my controler to my View without reloading all page.